# Update arguments for already created fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a fragment A and a fragment B.
Fragment A is called from 2 different screens (which are also fragments).

Now, fragment A passes arguments to fragment B, using setArguments(bundle), whenever called.

Like this:(These lines are written in Fragment A)

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("bookId", bookListItems.get(position).getBookId());
bundle.putString("bookName", bookListItems.get(position).getBookName());

Fragment b = new B();
b.setArguments(bundle);

replaceFragment(b, bundle);
```

and the function replaceFragment is as follows:

```
private void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment, Bundle bundle) {
  String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

  FragmentManager manager = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
  boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

  if (!fragmentPopped) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
     FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
     ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
     ft.commit();
   } else {
     fragment.getArguments().putString("bookId", bundle.getString("bookId"));
     fragment.getArguments().putString("bookName", bundle.getString("bookName"));
   }
}
```

Now, the problem is, when Fragment A is called from Screen 1, it works fine and passes right arguments to fragment B. But when it is called from Screen 2, the arguments passed to B are never updated, it always opens up the last state of fragment B.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you could create in your `Fragment`'s subclass which takes the new data, for instance, and call this method from the hosting Activity when you want to update it

```
public void updateData(String bookName, String bookId) {
   if (getView() == null) {
      return;
   }
   ((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.texviewid)).setText(bookName);

}
```

In your `Activity` you will have to keep a reference to the specific subclass, as class member.

Another approach could make use of a `BroadcastReceiver`. In your Fragment register it with a specific `IntentFilter` and from your Activity use a `LocalBroadcastManager` to broadcast locally the intent with the changes. You could  still use the same method, to update the UI. When onReceive is invoked, check the fragment status, and if it is in a *correct* status, extracts the data from the `Intent`, and call the method. E.g.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (isRemoving() || isDetached() || !isAdded()) {
          return;
      }
      // extract data from intent
      // call updateData
}
```